# Is this an ORMLite bug?

Tags: java, ormlite

There is an example in the `Where` API 4.48 on using the `where` clauses that goes exactly like this:

```
QueryBuilder<Account, String> qb = accountDao.queryBuilder();
Where where = qb.where();
// the name field must be equal to "foo"
where.eq(Account.NAME_FIELD_NAME, "foo");
// and
where.and();
// the password field must be equal to "_secret"
where.eq(Account.PASSWORD_FIELD_NAME, "_secret");
PreparedQuery<Account, String> preparedQuery = qb.prepareQuery();
```

But this does not work for me (`java.lang.IllegalStateException: No where clauses defined`) unless I do:

```
qb.setWhere(where);
```

before preparing the query. It looks like the internal `where` object is not mutating when the API suggests it should do so.

Have anyone else experienced the same?

UPDATE

It looks like not even calling `setWhere()` makes it work. I messed it up with my trials somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spotted the problem and it was my fault. While debugging, I was calling `where()` on the `QueryBuilder` object several times. But, as the documentation for the `where` method states:

> public Where<T,ID> where()
>
> Returns a Where object that should be used to add SQL where clauses to the statement. This will also reset the where object so you can use the same query builder with a different where statement.

The internal `where` object was being reset.

Comment: I've improved the javadocs for the `where()` method to make this more plain.

Comment: Thank you for keeping improving even for these small details. Cheers.